# How to use useEffect to change useState whenever a var is changed without triggering an infinite loop?

Tags: reactjs

in my react component, I am getting the following issue in my console

`index.js:1 Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render. at Id (http://localhost:3000/main.82c936520e7a7a921612.hot-update.js:32:27) at div at div at div at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:249:62)`

The number of time that error shows keeps increasing each new second, the same error is created again. I have no idea why because I thought my logic makes sense, how is it creating an infinite loop?

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactTooltip from "react-tooltip";

import { FaQuestionCircle, FaRedoAlt } from 'react-icons/fa';

interface Props {
    setId: React.Dispatch<React.SetStateAction<{data: number, componentRef: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>}>>;
    id : {data: number, componentRef:React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>};
}

const Id : React.FC<Props> = ( props : Props ) => {
    
    var idData = {...props.id};

    useEffect(()=>{
        props.setId(idData);
    }, [idData]);

    const generateNewId = () => {
        idData.data = Math.floor( Math.random()*1000 ) + 1; 
    }

    useEffect(()=>{
        generateNewId();
    },[])

    const modifyId = (sign : string) => {
        sign === "+" ? idData.data = idData.data + 1 : idData.data = idData.data - 1 ;
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <ReactTooltip id="counter-info">
                <p>A random ID is generated each time you click refresh</p>
                <p className="text-bold">What is ID?</p>
                <p className="text-bold">Your ID is added to the back of your username, to always ensure that you have a unique username</p>
            </ReactTooltip> 
            <h2>Your ID: {idData.data}
                <span data-tip data-for="counter-info">
                    <FaQuestionCircle/>
                </span>
            </h2>
            <button className="btn rounded-circle btn-dark" onClick={()=>modifyId("-")}>-</button>
            <button className="btn rounded-circle btn-dark mr-3" onClick={()=>modifyId("+")}>+</button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={()=>generateNewId()}><FaRedoAlt/></button>
        </div>
    )
    
}

export default Id;
```

In App.tsx

```
const idRef = React.useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
const [ id, setId ] = useState<{data: number, componentRef: React.RefObject<HTMLDivElement>}>(
    {
      data: NaN,
      componentRef: idRef
    }
  )
<div ref={idRef} className="col-3">
          <Id id={id} setId={setId}/>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Issues

1. You are setting the id passed to your props, with the setter function passed to your props: (This way every time this component renders, it sets the id, and since id is a prop, a re-render is triggered. Hence, an infinite loop of re-renders)

```
    var idData = {...props.id};

    useEffect(()=>{
        props.setId(idData);
    }, [idData]);
```

This is not necessary, since this is a controlled component, and you already passed the id to your child.

2. You are modifying the props directly in your `modifyId` function. Instead, assign it to a state variable and make changes to that state variable

#### Understanding dependency array

In `useEffect` the dependency array makes sure that, *that particular useEffect triggers only depending on your dependency array*

```
useEffect(() => console.log("run once"), [])
useEffect(() => console.log("run only id changes"), [id])
```

#### Solving your problem

Your problem is a little bit confusing to understand. Based on my understanding, you want to `setId` when you `modifyId`:

```
const Id : React.FC<Props> = ( props : Props ) => {
    
    const {id: idData} = props
    const [childId, setChildId] = useState({})

    useEffect(() => {
       if(idData) setChildId(idData)
    }, [idData])

    const generateNewId = () => {
        setChildId(Math.floor( Math.random()*1000 ) + 1)
    }

    const modifyId = (sign : string) => {
        setChildId(id => sign === '+' ? {...id, data: id.data + 1} : {...id, data: id.data-1})
    }

    return(
        <div>
            <ReactTooltip id="counter-info">
                <p>A random ID is generated each time you click refresh</p>
                <p className="text-bold">What is ID?</p>
                <p className="text-bold">Your ID is added to the back of your username, to always ensure that you have a unique username</p>
            </ReactTooltip> 
            <h2>Your ID: {childId.data}
                <span data-tip data-for="counter-info">
                    <FaQuestionCircle/>
                </span>
            </h2>
            <button className="btn rounded-circle btn-dark" onClick={()=>modifyId("-")}>-</button>
            <button className="btn rounded-circle btn-dark mr-3" onClick={()=>modifyId("+")}>+</button>
            <button className="btn" onClick={()=>generateNewId()}><FaRedoAlt/></button>
        </div>
    )
    
}

export default Id;
```

**PS: If you don't want to set a state variable, remove the `useState` call and replace setChildId with prop.setId**

Answer (score 0):

i see several mistakes in your code; passing an object as a dependency to `useEffect` is not a good idea, objects in js are a reference type, when your component runs again (re-render), each round the `idData` object will be recreated...

therefore, when the component runs again, the current object is unequal to the previous object that you passed to the `useEffect` dependency array and `useEffect` runs again... frequently, this process will be repeated constantly!

e.g:

```
{} === {} //flase!
```

in your case, you have to use `setId` when you wanna set a new id... or if you have to initialize it, you can set an empty array as the `useEffect` dependency.

Comment: How can `{} !== {}` when the objects have the same keys and values? Trying to understand

Comment: @argonx you have to perform a deep equal for comparing two object, you can use this tool for doing this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/deep-equal